# My HP Elitebook 8570w cannot power on after I changed the boot option from legacy to UEFI

Tags: boot, uefi

I changed my HP elitebook 8570w boot option from legacy to UEFI.
When I turn it on, the screen is off but the fan and other buttons are on.
What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are intending to install a new operating system you will have to power down, enter your firmware using whatever key combination is relevant during power up, and set it back to `legacy`.

Your operating system installs specific files and partition format depending on which mode (legacy or UEFI) it is installed under. The two modes are very different and have very different boot sequences.

Comment: How will I enter the firmware

Comment: @kenne https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebooks-Archive-Read-Only/how-to-enter-the-bios-in-an-hp-elitebook-8560w/td-p/1412867